# Mixing Lua and PHP?

Tags: php, lua

I really want to mix Lua and PHP, for example receive a PHP query and process some parts of the query using Lua scripts (being called from the PHP script that got the initial query ).

Any clues about this ? I've seen some libraries to use Lua as some kind of PHP replacement, but I've seen nothing clear about how to use both Lua and PHP together.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you seen [phplua](http://phplua.3uu.de/)? It looks like it could do what you want. I found it via the *Lua binding-with-other-languages* page (it was the only relevant option, for *better* or *worse*).

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but felt the whole thing was very young, and the API wasn't very nice. Still if it's the best option at the moment, I guess I will have to go with that.

Comment: I guess its youth and unfinished state may mean you can contribute to it and shape it to your own desires.  :)

Answer (score 6):

There is now a full PECL extension for embedding and interacting with Lua code.

See http://pecl.php.net/package/lua and http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.lua.php

Answer (score 3):

I assume you aren't feeling up to embedding lua in PHP which leaves running lua as an external script and reading the result. That's a pretty common operation and [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php) provides some guidance.